# How to calculate a meteor's entrance altitude to Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: meteor, meteor-shower

Also, in which altitude did fireball went thermal explosion?

Comment: What do you mean by "entrance altitude to Earth's atmosphere"? Are you asking at what height Earth's atmosphere ends?

Comment: Or do you mean angle?

Comment: I was going to suggest the [JPL Fireballs page](http://neo.jpl.nasa.gov/fireballs/) which records detected explosions. Typically 30-40 km altitude (highly variable) and as much as a few kilotonnes of impact energy. (The Chelyabinsk meteor is on the list too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a example [here](http://ogleearth.com/2013/02/reconstructing-the-chelyabinsk-meteors-path-with-google-earth-youtube-and-high-school-math/) of the process required. But basically you need observations of the track from two locations and then just perform some relatively simple trigonometric triangulation. The [Nemetode](http://www.nemetode.org/) network regularly does this using images from a network of cctv cameras.